# Is there a runtime way to configure the spring cloud uri?

Tags: cas, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to set up a Docker image for CAS deployment. We have two different spring cloud config servers, one for dev and one for production that are in different vlans/firewalls.

I don't want to store the spring cloud password in the war file, because I don't want secrets in the Docker image. I don't want different war files for different environments, I'd like to use the same war file everywhere.

Is there any way to configure the spring cloud uri at runtime?

I could change the Docker entrypoint to a shell script. That shell script would generate a new `bootstrap.properties` file, then copy it into the .war. That feels really hacky, but would accomplish my goal.

Comment: The Spring Cloud Config URI value comes from a configuration property. Spring Boot's [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) reads configuration properties from a variety of property sources. You can configure one of those property sources to override the value of the Spring Cloud Config URI.